# Change SQLAlchemy's Session.delete() behaviour

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

Are there any configuration possibilities concerning the `delete()`-method of SQLAlchemy's `Sessions`? I'd like to have the corresponding objects marked with a deleted flag in the database and not removed from it. Is there a way to achieve this? The aim is to build a database without destructive updates without losing the advantages of SQLAlchemy's cascading features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own session class inheriting from `Session` and override the `delete()` method with your own logic (for those classes that require `logical delete`), falling back to the default implemetation for the other objects. If you use [sessionmaker](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker) or similar factory, you can provide your class in the `class_` parameter as well.

Hopefully, this answers your question. But, having said/written that, there is ***SOOO MUCH MORE*** to the logical deletion especially in term of `Referential Integrity`, that one can write a series of articles on that.

Comment: Do you have any links to articles on implementing logical delte with sqlalchemy? Could you include some in your answer?

Comment: No, I have not implemented logical deletes with sqlalchemy yet.