# Deleting non existing record should raise an error in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why deleting non-existing record does not raise an error in sqlalchemy.
no feedback on whether the record was deleted or not.

```
session.query(Element).filter(Element.id==ElementId).delete()
```

Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it is an error.  For example it is perfectly legal to issue a query to delete records in sql that "don't exist"

If i have a table 'posts' with a column 'id'. with no records

`DELETE FROM posts WHERE ID > 0;`

It is perfectly valid sql, there is no error, even though there are no rows

I am not too familiar with sqlalchmey but could you check to see if value exists first?

```
element = session.query(Element).filter(Element.id==ElementId).first()
if element:
   # delete element
else:
   # raise exception
```

The above will issue an additional query though...

Also, if you want a `delete` method that raises error you can create your own session class
[Change SQLAlchemy's Session.delete() behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908571/change-sqlalchemys-session-delete-behaviour)
and override `delete`

As [zzzeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek) points out [`delete`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) with a criteria

> Returns the number of rows deleted, excluding any cascades.

Which is another option for seeing if any rows are deleted

Comment: delete() on criteria will return the number of rows matched, so you can assert on that.   otherwise this answer is correct, if you want a checked delete of an identity you have to use session.delete().

Comment: Thank you all, I'll try the suggested answer.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, sqlalchemy delete operation returns number of affected rows. So you can check and if affected rows is 0 then you can raise error.

```
effected_rows = session.query(Element).filter(Element.id==ElementId).delete()
if effected_rows == 0:
    # raise exception
else:
    # delete element
```

This works for me.

Comment: We can use TypeError for this (although some other exception might be better):

if (effected_rows == 0):
    raise TypeError("0 rows deleted")

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to @madogan, the edit queue was full and hence writing a new answer.

I've expanded his answer more in detail in a working solution:

```
class NoEntryFoundException(Exception):
    pass


def delete_row_entry(element_id: int):
    effected_rows = session.query(Element).filter(Element.id == element_id).delete()

    if effected_rows == 0:
        raise NoEntryFoundException(f'No row entry found with id: {element_id}')
    else:
        session.commit()
```