# Custom delete logic in flask-restless

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-restless

Due to the nature of my application I need some of my records to just set an `is_deleted` flag when being deleted.

Is there a way to do this in flask-restless upon receiving an HTTP `DELETE`?

Comment: Explore the [GlobalFilter recipy](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/GlobalFilter) to help you filter `is_deleted` out. In terms of deletion, just use your custom session implementation overriding the `delete` method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908571/change-sqlalchemys-session-delete-behaviour). Would appreciate your final solution being shared as well.